# How do I add an Action to a Project Node when writing a Netbeans plugin module

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, contextmenu, netbeans-plugins

I want to write a Netbeans plugin to allow the running of gulp.js tasks from a context menu on the project node.

How do I add extra items (Actions) to a Project node? I can't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register your action as shown in http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqActionAddProjectPopUp ? IIRC there is also a way to add the action to a specific project type.